# ForEach In List isn't targetting all

Tags: c#

so I currently have a program that adds an item to a list in a format such as
username,Index it then adds one to the index in this code below however. It is only adding one to the item that has been added most recently.

```
Console.WriteLine("There are currently: " + AntiSpam.Count);
int Index = 0;
foreach (string s in AntiSpam)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found User: " + s.Split(',')[0]);
    AntiSpam[Index] = s.Split(',')[0] + "," + (int.Parse(s.Split(',')[1]) + 1).ToString();
    Index++;
}
```

Basically this returns the data There are currently: 10
Found User: someone. It then goes again for another loop of this code and shows the same result again.

**EDIT**
I have managed to make my code work by using this code

```
        for (var i = 0; i < AntiSpam.Count; i++)
        {
            AntiSpam[i] = AntiSpam[i].Split(',')[0] + "," + (int.Parse(AntiSpam[i].Split(',')[1]) + 1).ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("Text is {0}", AntiSpam[i]);
        }
```

However if possible I would like to know why this works and the first doesn't

Comment: what are some sample values of `AntiSpam`?

Comment: Something such as 'hello,0' -- String + ',' + Int

Comment: It seems like this whole thing (minus the console writes) could be replaced with: `AntiSpam = AntiSpam.Select(a => { var split = a.Split(','); return $"{split[0]},{int.Parse(split[1]) + 1}"; });`

Comment: What is the type of AntiSpam? Is it a `List<T>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to be indexing a list, just do `for` rather than `foreach`. This avoids the need (and possible confusion) of using a separate variable to keep track of the `AntiSpam.IndexOf(s)` which is basically what you were trying to do with `Index`:

```
Console.WriteLine("There are currently: " + AntiSpam.Count);
int index;
string s;
for(int i=0; i < AntiSpam.Count, i++)
{
    string[] parts = AntiSpam[i].Split(',');
    username = parts[0];
    Console.WriteLine("Found User: " + username);
    if (parts.Length > 1)
    { 
        index = int.Parse(parts[1])
        AntiSpam[i] = username + "," + (index + 1).ToString();
    }
}
```